activemq 5.16.x not working after converting javax to jakarta using eclipse transformer
I am using eclipse transformer for javax to jakarta conversion, in the similar lines I converted my activemq-all 5.16.7 into jakarta using the same eclipse transformer, no errors during compilation, but while running the application it is not returning from below line:
"ConnectionFactory.createConnection()"
means it is not able to establish the connection with broker.
Appreciate any help.

Running a client jar through a byte-code translator to make it use jakarta instead of javax is unlikely to work and certainly not something that has been tested or is supported by the ActiveMQ community.
If you want to use Jakarta classes from a client connecting to ActiveMQ Classic then you'll need to either of the following:

activemq-client-jakarta from ActiveMQ Classic 5.18.1 and above
activemq-client from ActiveMQ Classic 6.x

Keep in mind that ActiveMQ Classic doesn't yet fully support JMS 2 (and therefore Jakarta Messaging 2 & 3.x). If you want full support for these you'll need to migrate to ActiveMQ Artemis.

If I upgrade my client to use activemq-client-jakarta, Can I continue to use same activemq-broker activemq-all 5.16.7? or do I need to upgrade this also to use activemq-all 5.18.3?

I don't understand what you mean by "activemq-broker activemq-all 5.16.7." Are you trying to connect a messaging client using Jakarta classes to ActiveMQ Classic 5.16.7 broker?

Yes exactly, my application runs on wildfly, I am going to do wildfly upgrade, in wildfly 27 onwards it moved to jakarta EE, hence I need to convert all javax to jakarta including jms, I uses activemq for my application(not the one provided by wildfly) and runs activemq broker externally, for couple of 3rd party jars I used eclipse transformer it worked perfectly fine for me, Not sure how to handle this in the case of activemq, I am using activemq 5.16.7, I tried transforming activemq-all 5.16.7 both in the client & broker, it is not working

I believe the newer ActiveMQ Classic Jakarta client will be compatible with the older ActiveMQ Classic broker. Have you tried this combination already?

yes, I tried earlier both with different versions it was working, now after javax to jakarta changes in my application,
client side earlier it was activemq-all 5.16.7, now I changed to below

org.apache.activemq
activemq-client-jakarta
5.18.3

activemq-broker as well
In the activemq broker side it was activemq-all 5.16.7 and did not changed, but this is not working, it is not returning from "ConnectionFactory.createConnection()"
no errors as well.

Also in the broker side I tried using activemq-all 5.18.3 but still the same issue, appreciate your help

If it doesn't work then you'll need to upgrade both the client and the broker so that they're compatible.

Geting below error: at line new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://.....:61618");
Connection soapRespQconnection = soapRespQFactory.createConnection();
jakarta.jms.JMSException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://10.253.13.74:61618
at deployment.c2oear-snapshot.ear/com.optinuity.c2o.util.JMSMessagePublisher.sendMessage(JMSMessagePublisher.java:64) ......
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://....:61618

Are you using a client and a broker with the same version?

Currently no, will try now, but quick question do I need to use activemq-client-jakarta in the broker as well? and in the broker code also I need to convert javax.jms to jakarta.jms or keep it javax.jms only?

I tried with activemq 5.18.3 in the broker as well but without jakarta conversion, no luck, same error

What do you mean "without jakarta conversion"?

I mean in the broker side code I am not converting javax to jakarta for jms

sorry for the confusion, please ignore the above statement, I meant to say even broker is  with activemq-5.16.7 or 5.18.3 it is not working, the whole thing after javax to jakarta in my application before that it is working fine, activemq-client-jakarta is not helping me
but the broker is up and running
:\Users\Administrator>netstat -an | findstr  61618
TCP    xxxxx:61618     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Finally resolved the issue with activemq-client-jakarta, thank you Justin
